# Customizing 12.04 from terminal

Tags: python, live-cd, customization, chroot

I recently read a blog post on customizing Ubuntu 9.04 (I believe) via the terminal. It explained how to download all the Linux base packages and create a Linux distro inside of a directory and then how to chroot that directory. Somewhere along the line I couldn't get a package to install that the tutorial needed so I had to drop the project altogether. I would like to continue with developing a distro but I can't seem to find the tutorial again and I've just purchased a brand new computer with all my files from my old one gone.

How would I go about downloading the base Linux files into a folder, chrooting that folder to install a few other programs, and then automatically starting a python script upon system boot (once the user has installed the system).

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean is [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch). Although it says "Live CD" in the title, you can include the option of installing the customized system on other computers.

Comment: This wasn't it but it pretty much explains the same steps thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your talking about [LFS i.e. Linux From Scratch project](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/)
It is a project that provides you with step-by-step instructions for building your own customized Linux system entirely from source and as you say from terminal (command line).

Current stable release of the book can be downloaded from [here.](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/downloads/stable/)

I hope this will help.

Comment: I was hoping to have a condensed tutorial (much like the blog I was reading). I'm on page 20 of LFS and it's good stuff and it's straight forward but all I'm wanting to do is download an image, set the repositories to Ubuntu's, install a few extra programs, and then set a python startup script as the main user interface or start up program. The LFS book (which I'm still reading) is just aging on my misery with an unintended taunt of "You're not ready yet." LOL